# Difference between "value.toString" and "value.toString()"

Tags: javascript

somewhere when I was going through a piece code I saw a line and I could not find any proper explanation of it on the internet.

```
value.toString and value.toString()
```

please if anyone could help me with the difference between the above two?

Comment: The first statement verifies that `value` has a truthy value for its `toString` property and the second statement attempts to execute it as a function.

Comment: @RıdvanSumset, [huh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)?

Comment: `toString()` is a method to convert a value to string. there is no such thing `toString`. maybe it's a property (or a method) under an object in your code.

Comment: @AndréDion I edited my comment to make it clearer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**value.toString()** -> It will convert any value to string and return that value.

**value.toString** -> It will work as a primitive value and it will create an object wrapper. That's why it will not give any error or warning instead it will return a reference to the toString method.

So in short value.toSting() will return a string and value.toString will return a reference to the toString method.

Comment: _“and value.toString will return an undefined”_ - no, it will return a reference to the toString method.

Comment: Yes you are right it will return a reference to the toString method

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing Like "toString" in javascript. 
Whereas the function toString() is used to convert value into the String value.

```
var a = 10;
a.toString();
// Here a will be converted into String ("10")
```

Comment: _“There is nothing Like "toString" in javascript. Whereas the function toString() [...]”_ - both are the same thing - `foo.bar` just _references_ a method `bar` of the `foo` object, whereas `foo.bar()` would _call_ the method.

Comment: toString returns the defination of the method. whereas toString() is a method of the Object Class

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
value.toString
```

checks whether the variable `value` has a property named `toString`. This statement

```
value.toString()
```

retrieves the property named `toString` and **invokes** it as a method of `value`.

I suppose the intention here is to avoid exceptions in case the `value` lacks a `toString` method:

```
// If the value has a toString method, invoke it:
value.toString && value.toString()
```

(Note that I replaced `and` with the `&&` operator.)

Normally, every JavaScript value will have a `toString` method (even numbers and Booleans!), so this extra test is unnecessary. Hypothetically one could construct an object where the `toString` property is explicitly erased:

```
var value = { toString: undefined };
```

and in this case, it would make sense to test for the existence of `toString` before attempting to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

The `value.toString` is a function in JavaScript which can be used
as 
`value.toString()`

If write and test `value.toString` in console you see below.

`ƒ toString() { [native code] }`

Comment: nope, `value.toString()` do not return that but `toString` does.